# Selecting a SerDes IC based on format

Tags: voltage, current, serial, high-speed

I have a query regarding selection of SerDes ICs. I need to select an IC which is compatible with 3 formats - 24bits, 32bits and 27bits.

[MAX9275](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9275-MAX9279.pdf) - Just a sample IC datasheet in the MAX SerDes GMSL family.

[image]

My question -

1. Can someone tell me what those 3 formats are and what they mean?
2. And how to search and find that information in the datasheet attached above

Any useful tips and information along the way regarding this question will help me a lot to select a particular IC in the MAX SerDes IC family.

**EDIT:**

[image]

I found that in the above image, 24 bits, 32bits and 27bits, how are they arrived?

RGB either comes as 666 or 888. So, RGB + Clock will either be 6667 (25bits) or 8887 (31 bits) ? Am I correct? Or what is the actual split up of 24bits, 32bits and 27bits? And why 27bits is specifically mentioned as high bandwidth mode?

Comment: "# RX" is "number of receivers, "# TX" number of transmitters, and seeing what SerDes stands for "27 bit" is the parallel bus width? Is that what you're asking? Not quite sure what you mean with "3 formats"?

Comment: Table 1 in the linked MAX9279 datasheet lists the supported formats: 24-bit (BWS=LOW), 27-bit (BWS=MID), and 32-bit (BWS=HIGH). I'm puzzled though why you're asking about the digital video standard format, and I don't see anything in your previous questions to suggest you're an automotive rear-seat entertainment systems designer or doing anything with digital video (the RX is an "authorized display" and TX are video sources which may include HDCP copy protection). This is not an entry-level part. Can you please explain your actual requirements? Do you really need video, or just plain SerDes?

Comment: I need video too. Just didn't know on what does the three formats does and how to identify in the datasheet

Comment: what is the actual split up of 24bits, 32bits and 27bits? ==> Table 1 Input Map column "Input Pin" details which I/O pin maps to which video or audio signal, and figure 15 shows how these map to the SerDes serial data (before 8b10b encoding, preemphasis, etc.). BTW you really can call Maxim directly, we have a whole team dedicated to handling customer requests like this.